# Sharepoint Designer Two level approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

I have a requirement with two level approval work flow, where i need to collect data from user forms Form1.aspx(First Approval) and Form2.aspx(Second Approval).

How do i carry the details of workflow initiator details to First Approval form and First Approval details to the second approval form.

I am using SPD Workflows collect data from user

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Save the values into a variable and then use them in the other form.